# Serial not declared in this scope, newbie mistake most likely

Tags: programming

Ok, newguy with a little VBA coding experience going to pull hair out soon. It is probably a simple thing I have missed but I would like someone to point out where I went wrong. I modified a sketch that used an lcd to use the serial monitor instead but I sometimes run into this "not declared in this scope" issue. Doing something wrong, please point me in the correct direction.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS3231 rtc;
DateTime now;
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};

void showDate(void);
void showTime(void);
void showDay(void);

void showDate()
{
  serial.print(now.day());
  serial.print('/');
  serial.print(now.month());
  serial.print('/');
  serial.print(now.year());
}

void showDay()
{
  serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
}

void showTime()
{
  serial.print("Time:");
  serial.print(now.hour());
  serial.print(':');
  serial.print(now.minute());
  serial.print(':');
  serial.print(now.second());
  serial.print("    ");
}

void setup ()
{
Serial.begin(9600);

  serial.println("working....")
  //wire.begin();
  //delay(2000);
  if (! rtc.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC Module");
    while (1);
  }

  if (rtc.lostPower())
  {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, lets set the time!");
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  }
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
}


void loop ()
{
  now = rtc.now();
  showDate();
  showDay();
  showTime();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case matters in C/C++. You should write `Serial` rather than `serial`.

Comment: OMG, I will not live that down!!!

Comment: Sorry, I will be more careful with that. I am used to VBA where if you @@$ up syntax it highlights it. Thanks for your quick answer. Hiding head now, lol

Comment: As a nebie I also noticed that when syntax is valid the color of the code is red/orange. Are functions highlighted in the IDE?

Comment: Built-in functions appear to be highlighted in orange, reserved words in blue-ish. Strings in Green-ish? Pretty sure it doesn't parse your code to highlight specific to your project.